# Finding closest value in array of custom objects in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I do have array of custom objects in swift, like below

Objects of below class

```
Class Person {
  let name: String
  let pointsEarned: CGFloat
}
```

Array is like below

```
let person1 = Person(“name1”, “5.6”)

let person2 = Person(“name2”, “6.6”)

let person3 = Person(“name3”, “1.6”)

let persons = [person1, person2, person3 ]
```

I would like find person who’s earned points are close to 7.0

Is there extension on array I can write for this?

Appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Distance from 7 is just `abs(7 - pointsEarned)`, so sort the objects by whichever has the lowest distence

Comment: Can you please provide code snippet? I am missing something

Comment: `people.sort { abs(7 - $0.score) < abs(7 - $1.score) }`

Comment: Thanks! It’s working

Comment: You are using `sort`, and then it's `people.sort{ insideClosure }.first` while it could just be `people.min(by: { insideClosure }`

Comment: @Larme Ah yes, I misread the question. If you only want the winner, use `min(by:)`.

Answer (score 1):

Sort your objects by their distance from the goal (`7`)`, computed as`abs(goal - score)`:

```
people.sort { abs(7 - $0.score) < abs(7 - $1.score) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alexander's answer is good, but you only need the `min`.

```swift
public extension Sequence {
  func min<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    by getComparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows -> Element? {
    try self.min {
      try getComparable($0) < getComparable($1)
    }
  }
}
```

I also think `abs` as a global function looks archaic. `magnitude` is the same value.

```
persons.min { ($0.pointsEarned - 7).magnitude }
```

You can use the argument label with a trailing closure if you want:

```swift
persons.min(by:) { ($0.pointsEarned - 7).magnitude }
```

Comment: Woah, didn't know about `magnitude`. That's so much better!